# I want to Pass Django's url to form's action using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to do something like below in my Django project

Question : I want to Pass Django's page url to form's action using Javascript

Query: Actually It is working but "How can I pass any argument with this URL"

Working Code: last line of js is working because I am passing custom value i.e. 1

```
<form id="book_hotel" action="{% url 'payment' hotel.price %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
        .
        .
        .
</form>

<script>
    function calculate() {
        room = document.getElementById('room').value
        night = document.getElementById('night').value
        var hotel_price = "{{ hotel.price }}"
        var total_price = hotel_price*room*night
        document.getElementById('payment_button').innerHTML='Pay &#8377;'+total_price;
        document.getElementById('book_hotel').action = "{% url 'payment' 1 %}"
    }
</script>
```

Not Working Code:
if chang last line of my javascript to given as below

```
document.getElementById('book_hotel').action = "{% url 'payment' " + total_price + "%}"
```

It is not working.

So How can I pass 'total_price' argument in javascript

I know Question is bit messy so please comment below to get more clarification.

Thank You!!

Comment: document.getElementById('book_hotel').action = "{% url 'payment' " + total_price + "%}"

The code above is wrong，String  plus is running in browser after url filter is running at server side.
If you want to change action dynamicly in browser, you can not use server side url reversing, you should generate the url by the javascript code which running in the browser.

Comment: Okay so How can I generate URL by JavaScript code. If you have any suggestions then please share with me

Comment: simulate url reverse logic by javascript code